# UEFI questions after moving to Ubuntu 14.10 finally

Tags: boot, 14.10, uefi, laptop

I have a couple of questions after I switch to Ubuntu for my main OS on my laptop and they are:

1. Will I have to install a bootloader of sorts into my UEFI to boot straight into Ubuntu?, like without going into F9 and selecting Ubuntu (HDD Serial)
2. Will UEFI accept Ubuntu as the main OS afterwords without problems?

   3. Will I have to change anything else to make this work?

Sorry for the list of questions, I would not ask these if on an older setup like an older laptop, but I'm just scared to screw something up.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have any problems. GRUB has an EFI version, and should set itself as default during the install. What you need to do, however, is boot the installation in EFI mode and not just selecting it in the boot menu. If your BIOS can select to boot from an EFI file, you need to go into the drive and select the `grubx64.efi` file somewhere under `EFI`.

Comment: It does but I want my laptop to boot into Ubuntu 14.10 64 Bit without me touching anything. and I have a 64 bit version of Ubuntu 14.10 on a 1.7 GB DVD -RW but in the corner, says "booting in insecure mode", is that what you mean?

Comment: What brand/model laptop? Some just work, Some require work arounds. With the new UEFI, you have three boot modes, UEFI secure boot, UEFI and CSM. CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode  Ubuntu can boot in any of those modes, but often easier to not have secure boot on for now. Later we may want it. Is UEFI the most current version from Vendor? And how you boot installer is how it installs. So you want to boot flash  drive in UEFI mode.

Comment: Zacharee1's comment is sound, but for more detail, see [my Web page on EFI-mode Linux installations.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) I believe that should answer most of your questions.